# I cannot draw a simple line in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I'm trying to drawing a simple line using a dialog but when I compile my code nothing happens,  I have the dialog without nothing, please any body could explain me what is happening?
Below my code:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QPainter>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::paintEvent(QPainter *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawLine(10,10,100,100);
}
```

I don't know what is wrong

Comment: If you are using C++11 you should use an `override` keyword to prevent such errors.

Answer (score 3):

This line is wrong:

```
void Dialog::paintEvent(QPainter *)
```

It has the wrong arguments-signature, so it is not getting called.  It should instead be:

```
void Dialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
```